# url template tage variable not being parsed django

Tags: python, django, templates, url, view

I am trying to dynamically generate links in my template of the form ..../hub/username/ but am always getting back only ..../hub for some reason. I have read through the docs several times and it seems very clear what to do, but I am just making some mistake somewhere I suppose!
Please Help!

I have in my urls:

```
urlpatterns = patterns(
    '',
    url(r'^hub/(.+)/$', 'hub.views.hub_view', name="hub"),
    ...
    ...
)
```

I have in my template:

```
 <li><a id="todoMenuButton" href="{% url 'hub' user.username %}">ToDo</a></li>
```

template context preprocessors is enabled in my settings:

```
TEMPLATE_CONTEXT_PROESSORS = (
    'django.core.context_processors.request',
)
```

Thanks!

Comment: Are you passing `RequestContext` to the template?

Answer (score 0):

Instead of adding the `request` context processor to the default set, you've overwritten the defaults with that single one. That means there is no `user` variable defined in the context. You could use `request.user` instead, but it would be better to fix your seeing as there are other useful processors you are missing out on (eg debug).

Answer (score 0):

It was a simple mistake, I was using the todo button instead of the hub button :/

Sorry!

Thanks!